# Distribution of a Poisson process with uniformly random parameter

Tags: probability, integration, uniform-distribution, poisson-distribution

Let $X = Unif(2, 4)$ and $Y=Poisson(X)$.  My goal is to find $P(Y=n)$, but I always seem to get stuck on some nasty integral.  Here's what I've tried:

$P(Y=n) =\int_2^4P(Y=n|X=x)*P(X=x)dx = \int_2^4 e^{-x}x^{n}/n!*1/2  dx$

I can see that the $n!$ is a constant, so this is just
$1/(2*n!)*\int_2^4 e^{-x}x^{n}dx$

However, I've got no clue how to make progress on that integral, because $n$ is arbitrary.  I'd accept an answer that either helps me to find a closed form formula for that integral or another route of tackling this problem that finds a closed form answer for $P(Y=n)$.

Comment: $n$ integration by parts. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was probably proven in class or it is given in the text that if $Z\sim\text{Gamma}(r, \lambda)$, then the cdf is
$$F_Z(z) = 1-\sum_{k=0}^{r-1}e^{-\lambda z}\frac{(\lambda z)^k}{k!}.$$
Then notice that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2\cdot n!}\int_2^4 e^{-x}x^{n}dx
&=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{2\cdot n!}\int_2^4\frac{1}{\Gamma(n+1)}1^{n+1}x^{(n+1)-1}e^{-x}\,dx \tag 1\\
&=\frac{n!}{2\cdot n!}\left[F_Z(4)-F_Z(2)\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}
\left[1-\sum_{k=0}^{n}e^{-1\cdot 4}\frac{(1\cdot 4)^k}{k!}-\left(1-\sum_{k=0}^{n}e^{-1\cdot 2}\frac{(1\cdot 2)^k}{k!}\right)\right],
\end{align*}
where I recognize $(1)$ as the density of a $\text{Gamma}(r = n+1,\lambda=1)$.